# How to automatically hyperlink variables in equations?

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to make a hyperlinked equation sheet. Locally, for a section/subsection/subsubsection... of my document I'd like LaTeX to automatically hyperlink each variable to a description of the variable.

Comment: Are you willing to replace $x$ with \hx?  Of course you would have to create hyperlink macros  (like \hx) for each variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what \hx does.

Comment: It wasn't specified, but for example `\newcommand{\hx}{\hyperlink{definition.x}{$x$}}` where definition.x  is the \hypertarget to be linked to.  It could also be made math style sensitive with a lot more work.